# JQuery DataTable columns become visible again

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using this code to respond to a JQuery DataTable 'draw' event and use it to hide some columns, depending on a parameter value to the method in question.

```
    AP.MaterialTable.on('draw',
        function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    if (countrycode === 'BR') {
                        AP.MaterialTable.column(6).visible(false);
                        AP.MaterialTable.column(7).visible(true);
                        AP.MaterialTable.column(8).visible(true);
                    } else {
                        AP.MaterialTable.column(6).visible(true);
                        AP.MaterialTable.column(7).visible(false);
                        AP.MaterialTable.column(8).visible(false);
                    }
                },
                100);
        });
```

However, if the user interacts with the DataTable on the page, the hidden columns suddenly reappear. 'Interact', in this case, being anything like sorting by a column or even opening the browser developer console.

Comment: Is your event handler firing?

Comment: The event handler fires when the table finishes rendering, but does not fire when the (eg) table is sorted or (eg) the browser's developer console is opened.